# C# Extension Method for Null or value

Tags: c#, extension-methods

How to   write an extension method  that should check value  of the object,if object is null   then
it  should return null  otherwise  value{without doing casting at  receiving end}.

something like...

```
public static object GetDefault(this object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return null;
    else return obj;
}
```

I   mean  without   casting  can i check  for  null?

```
int? a=a.GetDefault();

ContactType type=type.GetDefault();   [For EnumType]

string  s=a.GetDefault()
```

Comment: The requirement appears to be pointless. Just assign the object directly to the nullable type.

Comment: If null, return null, otherwise return value... How is that different to using the value right away?

Comment: @GSerg The code in the question is just a prototype, lacking the important bit. :) (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T GetObject<T>(this T obj, T def)
    {
        if (default(T).Equals(obj))
            return def;
        else
            return obj;
    }
}
```

I've added a parameter `def` because I expected you to want to return this default value when obj is null. Otherwise, you can always leave out the `T def` parameter and return `null` instead.

Comment: No need for the `def` parameter. That's what the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword is for.

Comment: In a world where this method is useful, how about just `return obj ?? def;`

Comment: @Oded, I assume this allows you to say `foo.GetDefault(new Foo { Bar = 7 })`, which will give you some default instance of `Foo` if `foo` is null.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - Better yet: `return obj ?? default(T);`

Comment: @Oded: I added the def parameter because your comment to the question :).

Comment: @Oded, which for a nullable type is effectively the same as `return obj ?? obj;` or simply `return obj;`, because `default(T)` will be null.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - I guess it was not clear to me that the passed in object _is_ nullable.

Comment: @Oded - Well it must be, or the null coalescing operator would be useless, as would the check for null. But it looks like he stealthily edited the answer a bit, so I'm commenting on code that is now changed.